# Reading from terraform_remote_state with AzureRM provider

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy a VNET in one module and store the ID of the subnet in remote state in Azure Blob Storage.

I see that my output seems to be stored correctly in the remote state blob.

The problem arises when I'm trying to read the Subnet ID in another module

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name  = "mystorage"
    container_name        = "tfstate"
    key                   = "terraform.tfstate"

  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "defaultsubnet" {
  name  = "default"
  address_prefix = "10.10.1.0/24"
  resource_group_name = "my-rg"
  virtual_network_name = "my-vnet"
}

output "id" {
  value = "${azurerm_subnet.defaultsubnet.id}"
}
```

```
"outputs": {
                "id": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/my-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/my-vnet/subnets/default"
                },
```

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "sub" {
  backend = "azurerm"
  config = {
    storage_account_name = "mystorage"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"

  }
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
.....
    agent_pool_profile {
        vnet_subnet_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.sub.id}"
    }
}
```

vnet_subnet_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.sub.id}"

This line fails with the following message:

> Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n*
>   azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks: Can not parse
>   \"agent_pool_profile.0.vnet_subnet_id\" as a resource id: Cannot parse
>   Azure ID: parse 2019-04-09 15:21:55.916021 +0000 UTC: invalid URI for
>   request\n\n\n"}

Somehow it's casting the subnet ID as Date. And even thought I've found a similar issue here https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20147 I'm still not able to apply that workaround to my case.

Comment: We used this pattern many times without issues in 0.11.x. Can you share a little more about? Which Terraform version?

Comment: Sure, we're using 0.11.13 if I'm not wrong, but I'm confident that it's not 0.12 yet. I'll gladly share more info if you give me a hint about what you'd like to know. Thanks :)

Comment: I checked our code is following the same pattern as yours, so we should look at something else. We use this pattern when producer and consumer code are in different directories; each dir use a different container/key for state. Is this your case?

Comment: Almost. We use different directories for consumer and producer code, e.g. "modules/azure/vnet" is used for networking modules and "modules/azure/aks" contains our AKS related modules. However, I'm using the same remote state container/key for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where possible you should avoid using the remote state data source and use native data sources that work against your provider.

In this case you should use the [`azurerm_subnet` data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/d/subnet.html) instead:

```
data "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  name                 = "default"
  virtual_network_name = "my-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "my-rg"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  #...
  agent_pool_profile {
    vnet_subnet_id = "${data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. First of all, I have to admit that I'm only starting my journey to Terraform, so I apologize for blunt questions and comments. 

If I follow your recommendation and use azurerm_subnet data source, how do I fulfill the requirement that the network infrastructure must be provisioned in the first TF module, while AKS must be done in the second module?

Comment: The data source won't find anything if the subnet hasn't been created and so will error out causing the AKS cluster to fail to be created if the subnet hasn't been created.

Comment: yes, makes sense, I'll try to use your approach. Thanks!